# Best way to do something with root permissions inside a sandboxed app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, jailbreak

What's the best method to edit a file requiring root permission from a MobileSubstrate tweak hooked to a sandboxed app (app store app)?

I have looked at SandCastle 2, however I couldn't find how I should implement it.